# Como montar uma array com valores do tagsinput bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando um tagsinput do bootstrap para inserção de valores no bd, porém os valores estão sendo armazenados em uma unica string, exemplo: "256,257,299".
Eu gostaria que esses valores fossem definidos em uma array e ficasse desta forma: ["256", "257", "299"], ai dou um foreach e cada valor vai para seu devido lugar no bd. Da forma que esta hoje, tudo em uma unica string somente o primeiro id esta sendo enviado para o bd.

Alguém sabe como realizar este procedimento?

Este é meu input:

```html
<input type="text" id="taginput" data-role="tagsinput" name="idrelacionado[]">
```

Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Ja pensou em usar o `split()`?

Comment: O split não é obsoleto?, O bootstrap também indica utilizar desta forma: <select multiple data-role="tagsinput" name="idrelacionado[]></select>.
Já testei e atende minha necessidade, mas não sei se é a forma mais correta.

Comment: por que o `split` seria obsoleto? O bootstrap indica fazer assim, porém não entrega em um formato de array, mas sim um formato mais fácil para você transformar o valor em um array usando o `split`

Comment: No php.net diz que está função está obsoleta na versão 5.3.0 e foi removida da versão 7. Ai são apresenteadas outras alternativas de uso.

Comment: Ah, pensei que estávamos falando de JavaScript. Php não posso ajudar mto, mas já que a documentação diz que é obsoleto, veja qual a alternativa que ele te da.

Comment: Engraçado que na página do tagsinput - Bootstrap diz que utilizando esse select multiple os valores serão setados em uma array, como você pode ver: Use a <select multiple /> as your input element for a tags input, to gain true multivalue support. Instead of a comma separated string, the values will be set in an array. Existing <option /> elements will automatically be set as tags. This makes it also possible to create tags containing a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forma com que resolvi o problema:

No meu form possuo o seguinte input ([tagsinput](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)):

```html
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="idrelacionado">
```

Recebo essa string na seguinte variável:

```html
$idrelacionado = $_POST['idrelacionado'];
```

Aplico o [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) na variável que armazena a string, aonde o delimitador é a virgula "," e armazeno em outra variável.

```html
$idre = explode(',', $idrelacionado);
```

Depois basta dar um foreach na variável que armazena o explode.

Comment: Esta seria a minha resposta, que bom que você chegou na solução sozinho. Parabéns!

Comment: Obrigado @IvanFerrer.

Answer (score 0):

Pronto, o que um Google não resolve.

"Php split deprecated what to use instead" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813241/php-split-alternative

**UPDATE**

Pronto cara, outro Google e achei sua resposta, [link](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Como todo componente jQuery, você consegue fazer "mágicas" com JavaScript.

Como você pode ver, já na primeira página, já tem o que você precisa.

`$("input").tagsinput('items')`

Chamando o método `items` do seu componente `tagsinput` te retorna os valores em um array.

Comment: Sim existem as alternativas PHP não procurei utilizá-las ainda pois estava querendo saber se iria conseguir chegar a uma solução somente com o Bootstrap, pois na página são apresentadas formas de como utilizar a ferramenta que me parecia talvez haver uma opção de como resolver o problema. E como lhe informei também já tinha visualizado as alternativas do split.

Comment: Mas muito obrigado pela orientação, estarei estudando para  futuramente se necessário implementar. Me parece que o str_split
seja uma boa opção.

Comment: Caro Gustavo, a forma com que você se dirige a resposta da a entender como se eu não pesquisasse antes de efetuar a pergunta no fórum, já tentei utilizar jquery para resolver este problema mas não consegui ou não soube implementar. Como sou iniciante as vezes pode faltar nomenclaturas para pesquisa no Google, encadeando resultados não satisfatórios.

Comment: No script: $("input").tagsinput('items') no lugar do input devo colocar o id do meu input ? Esse script vai na na head ?

Comment: Isso, mas no caso como é um id, você deve por um `#` na frente do id do input, sem espaço, colado com o id

Comment: hum... esse script pode ser inserido no corpo do html tbm, antes do input ? e é só chamar dentro da tag script ? Cara pior que já tentei utilizar isso mais não funcionava nem a pal, vou tentar de novo, quem sabe da certo.

Comment: Você tem que usar isso numa tag script, depois do seu HTML todo, antes de fechar o body. Não me leve a mal, mas depois desta pergunta sugiro você dar uma estudada em tecnologias web, HTML, JavaScript jQuery. Tente assinar a alura.com.br , vale muito o investimento.

Comment: Porque "depois dessa pergunta", como lhe informei sou iniciante comparado ao grande conhecimento de outros, realmente na parte das "tags scripts" perguntei não sei porque, pois script tem que estar dentro das tags script, mas nada que eu precise né aprofundar estudando html e tecnologias web, pois as vezes comemos bola e não é por falta de conhecimento, mas sim pela forma de se expressar, talvez falando pessoalmente isso não soaria com tanta falta de conhecimento. Mas de qualquer forma, obrigado pela dica da escola.

Comment: É, pela maneira que perguntou sobre usar script antes e fora de tag script deu uma assustada. A importância de usar o script por último se deve ao fato de que se ele for importado antes, ele vai executar e quando ele executar o seu elemento com o id de taginputs ainda não existe, aí não vai funcionar e você vai sofrer um pouco até entender o motivo.

Comment: Valew Gustavo, estarei implementado esse script a minha aplicação. Se der êxito, estarei postando o código aqui. é nozis!

Comment: Blz, qualquer coisa procura no Hangouts

Comment: * giovane.bds@gmail.com, e é Giovane haha

Answer (score 0):

Olá tive o mesmo problema e a solução não foi nenhuma das apresentadas aqui e nem pesquisando no google resolvi rsrs, eu quase estava usando outro script ai quando foi implementar vi que ele utiliza o campo select ao inves de input ai eu pensei pow ai a solução, só foi colocar o campo como select aidionei os items no js e coloquei os coxetes no name do campo e deu certo, então vamos lá o passso a passo..

Javascript

```
tagsinput('items');
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Campo Array</label><br>
<select name="NomeCampoArray[]" data-role="tagsinput" multiple="multiple" multiple data-placeholder="Digite as tags separadas..." value="<?php print_r($NomeCampoArray);?>">
<optgroup label="NomeCampoArray">
</select>
</div>
```